# Sequence of polynomials $p_n$ converging to a non-polynomial. Show $\text{deg}\, p_n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

If $f\in C[a,b]$ is not a polynomial, then show that for any sequence of polynomials $p_n$ that converges to $f$ uniformly, one must have that $\text{degree of } p_n \to\infty$.

Comment: As a general rule on this site, it'd be much better if you shared your thoughts and attempts before asking for help.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Assume that you have a sequence of polynomials of bounded degree ($\le n$) that converges uniformly on the interval $[a,b]$ to a function $f$ ( the interval being of length $b-a>0$). The space of polynomials of degree $\le n$ is finite dimensional of dimension $n+1$. Any two norms on such a space are equivalent. Hence the norm $p \mapsto \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |p(t)|$ is equivalent to the norm
$a_0+a_1 t + \cdots a_n t^n \mapsto \max ( |a_0|, \ldots , |a_n|)$. Hence if the sequence converges in the first norm it will converge in the second norm, and so,  to a polynomial.

Comment: Don't you need to use that $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and get rid of $f$ to use your argument? Because $p \mapsto \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |p(t)-f(t)|$ itself is not a norm on the space of polynomials of degree $\le n$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: You are totally correct, one goes through the argument as follows: convergent in 1st norm $\implies$ Cauchy in first norm$\implies$Cauchy in second norm $\implies$ convergent in second norm to a polynomial$\implies$ convergent in 1st norm to a polynomial, so $f$ a polynomial. Being only a hint, I skipped this chain.